# How can I open a transaction with a custom annotation

Tags: spring-boot, transactions

now

```
public void exec(){
   Connection conn = null;
   try{
       Connection conn = getConnection();
       save(user1,conn);
       update(school,conn);
       delete(home,conn);
       conn.commit()
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
       conn.rollback();
    }finally{
      conn.close();
   }
}
getConnection(){
    conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
}
save(entity,conn){
   String SQL = createSQL(entity);
   stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL,ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
   
}
```

but I hope

```
@myTransactional
public void exec(){
   save(user1);
   update(school);
   delete(home);
}
```

spring boot
just druid
no jdbctemplate

In annotation How can I get connection?
How can I commit or rollback?
Or there are other implementations?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the annotation? Is it simply opening and closing the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps but you could possibly use Spring's AOP functionality to implement the logic by adding your custom AOP annotation above a method.

You can read up on it here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop